# Unity GAv4 Plugin - LogScreen not visible, LogEvent is visible

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-analytics

I am adding Google Analytics tracking to my Unity game (opted in for GA instead of Firebase). I'm using GA v4, just downloaded this morning from Google, and Unity version 2018.3.14f1.

I've imported GAv4 package, have setup property ID (for Android, iOS and Others) in prefab, added prefab to hierarchy and I'm able to start session and send event using LogEvent method. These are visible in GA backoffice, I can see my device in real-time, device location and events it's firing.

However, problem is that it does not show LogScreen in the backoffice.

Here is the line that calls LogScreen:

```
googleAnalytics.LogScreen(new AppViewHitBuilder().SetScreenName("main_menu"));
```

This line is called after `googleAnalytics.StartSession()` so should be fine.

Just as a reference, here is my line to send GA event (which works and is visible in analytics console):

```
googleAnalytics.LogEvent(new EventHitBuilder().SetEventCategory("event_category").SetEventAction("event_action"));
```

I can't figure out what's the issue, as events are working fine, but LogScreen is not.

I would expect to see `LogScreen` shown in *Active Page* feed in GA real-time overview tab, but I can't see it, neither there nor anywhere else.

I have tested it on Android device only, Android 9, Xiaomi Mi8 Pro.

Also important notice: when running inside Unity IDE, it has no errors thrown but no data (even session and events) are not shown in GA console. Session and events ARE visible in GA console when running on mobile device.

Any directions on what am I doing wrong would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something else. GA is shutting down. Maybe you get the error because GA might restrict the access for the new comers. Your code seems okay.

https://www.semetis.com/en/resources/publications/google-will-shut-down-analytics-for-mobile-apps-in-2019

Comment: You are correct, GA for mobile apps will be gradually removed / shut down. It doesn't make sense to try to make it work (issue in my question) and I've migrated to Google Firebase instead.